# Relevance of questions on the performing of music

Tags: discussion

Are questions about things that are not music performance but relevant to the performing of music still on topic? We had somewhat of a differance in opinion in regards to this in [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/37765/the-rules-of-applause) question

Comment: Would you consider a question on topic if someone was to ask what  they should wear to a classical music concert or how much a ticket should cost? What about if your question was about rock or jazz instead of classical music, would you still consider it on topic?

Comment: Also related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/685/7222

Comment: There's some gray area but your question is far past the line IMO.  As questions about being a fan on Music Fans.

Comment: You have to admit that issues around applause do have a certain history about them that are worth learning about.

Comment: There are so many topics worth learning about and there are so few SE sites. Certainly no single SE site can reasonably be tasked with discussing all worthwhile music-related topics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked question is off topic because it is a question from/about the *audience* side of the performance.

I can imagine applause related questions that are on topic because they come from the performer side.  Performers may have questions with respect to managing their stage presence during applause, and these could be on topic.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question as written should have been posted to music fans, but I believe there are plenty of questions related to performance practice and programming that could be written from the perspective of the performer.

For example, there are some unspoken rules about programming art song, whereby you would typically group together songs by language, and applause would only come after each set. By contrast, every classical musician knows there shouldn't be applause between movements, and this difference in context and audience *for the question* is exactly why we have multiple sites and off-topic close votes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question about applause is useful because it gets at how people can distinguish between the ends of movements and the ends of whole pieces; this is a valuable question that has both historical and theoretical implications. Also, given that the answers given are very good, I think this question and others like it should stay. It is entirely likely that many questions that may work well in other stack exchange communities also work well here.